# Build more iOS Apps with the same project: Language strings

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I need to maintain a project that produces two applications. 
I've created two targets that share all the view Controller and Models. The only difference in these targets are storyboards and a couple of configuration files.

For `Localizable.strings` file I don't see any problem, as I said View Controllers and Models are shared and I've used `NSLocalizedString` function in these files. My doubts are related to the `.storyboard` files translation. Since the storyboards are really similar (they differ for the most for colors, position of some elements and for a couple of label text) I feel that is useless to maintain different strings file that contains almost the same data.
Any suggestion? Is there a way to use the same translation file for different storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are identical, I would move to [Base Internationalization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW2) and keep the text in .strings files rather than in localized .storyboard files.